# What do we do with all the [google-reader] questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

There are currently 197 questions tagged with [google-reader](/questions/tagged/google-reader) on Stack Overflow.

Now that the service has been discontinued, what should be done to all of them?

Do we delete them, or keep them around for the legacy/history/completeness?

Comment: Annnnnd this is why we got rid of too localized.

Comment: Why delete them?

Comment: Why do *anything* with them at all?

Comment: Wikipedia called. They want their deletionists back.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We keep them. There is no need to get rid of a source of potentially excellent questions and answers just because they have a tag of an outdated/no longer existing technology.

First of all it's too broad a generalization to say that all posts with that tag are of no use any more. And they do no harm to begin with.

At most update the tag Wiki to indicate the status of Google Reader.

Comment: So I guess its a "Keep them around for completeness"?

Comment: Meh, more a "I see no reason to delete it in the first place" @RaghavSood.

Comment: +1 to updating the tag wiki.